# Having multiple forms in asp.net page:Drawbacks?

Tags: asp.net, forms

Ok,I went through suggested questions which are concerned with
"Multiple forms in a single asp.net page".

I want to know if there are any drawbacks in using multiple forms.

A little background on my issue,I am using YUI dialog in an asp.net page.
YUI dialog works with an html form.
So,ultimately,I was having two nested forms inside a single page.

To workaround,
I closed the asp.net form just before my dialog code and when dialog code is finished,
Am having another form :

```
<form  method="post" action="#">
```

So that further semantics are preserved.
Ok,Do you guyz see anything wrong with this approach that might be encountered considering asp.net model.

Just wanted to know the opinion ..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using aspnet web forms? In which case multiple forms are not supported - the client side javascript libraries assume one form and the server side will barf if you have more than one form with runat=server.

Are you posting back to different urls in each form? This also is a problem in web forms. I think a bit more information is required, please ;-).

Comment: No.Only one runat=server form.the issue "was" that YUI dialog is must be inside a simple form.So,that was causing issue of nested form.So,I close the form tag before the yui and start another form tag with syntax as shown in above line .Am assuming ,action='#'  actually restore those semantics of server side form.Am i right?Consider a general master page scenario